# Reverse timeline code for as3

Tags: actionscript-3

How would I get to play backwards a timeline from a specific frame to another frame?

I need to be able to play back from frame 62 to 1 and from 101 to 62 depending on what frame I am on.  I know I can do 2 if loops with `if (currentFrame == 62)` etc but what is the code to play the timeline in reverse for AS3?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like this:

```
stop();

var targetFrame:int = 62;
// if we are ahead of the target, start going backwards
if(currentFrame > targetFrame) stage.addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME,goBack);

function goBack(evt:Event):void
{
    prevFrame();
    // kill the event listener when the target is reached
    if(currentFrame <= targetFrame) stage.removeEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME,goBack);
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use Greensock's TweenLite class to tween frames of your timeline in either direction.

```
Tweenlite.to ( mc, 1, {frame:1} );
```